# I accidentally remove the usb when live

Tags: boot, kali-linux, usb-drive

Can someone show me how to fix this please ?
[image]

Here some more information about kernel version and ram

Linux kali 6.0.0-kali3-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.0.7-1kali1 (2022-11-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

|  | total | used | free | shared | buff/cache | available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mem | 7867104 | 1197352 | 5094656 | 451168 | 1575096 | 5966072 |
| Swap | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |

Comment: Maybe `sudo reboot`? If it's totally hung, just press reboot/power cycle it.

Comment: Please can you tell me why this happened?

Comment: No idea but I'm 99% sure the USB flash removal has nothing to do with that. What kernel version are you running? (`uname -a`) Have you got enough RAM? (`free`) - please edit your question and add this info.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux Stack Exchange! Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: I think I have enough RAM